# Unable to style nested Alloy views

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I've got one view that 's another view in it's XML document. Here's the top-level view with the :

**windowBase.xml:**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="base">

        <Window class="content">

            <Label class="haveActivation" text="Have an activation code for this device?">

        </Window>
        <Require id="navigation1" class="navigation1" src="navigation" />

    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

And here are the styles for that view:

**windowBase.tss:**

```
".navigation1": {
    top: 692,
    left: 100,
    height: 265
}

".content": {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    height: 692,
    top: 0
}

".haveActivation": {
    bottom: 10
}
```

And here is the child navigation view:

**navigation.xml:**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="nav" id="nav" onClick="nav_click">

        <Label class="tabExample" text="Tab here">

    </View>
</Alloy>
```

And the styles for the navigation view:

**navigation.tss:**

```
"#nav": {
    zIndex: 9999,
    backgroundImage: "Navigation-Background.png",
    width: 1024,
    height: 265
}

".tabExample": {
    color: "white"
}

".container": {
    backgroundColor: "white"
}
```

You can see I've got the required view (.navigation1) top style set to 692. When it displays, however, it renders the view in the middle of the screen instead of at the bottom. The only way I'm able to get it to render at top:692 is if I put that style in the navigation view's #nav style, which doesn't seem to make a lot of sense.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can put a class on a Require.

Merge the .navigation1 class into the nav id styling in navigation.xml and delete the navigation1 class.  Your logic is a little redundant anyway, by trying to style from the include, you might as well style from the included file itself.

Answer (score 0):

To my way of thinking：

1. Window can't include other window in .xml file 
   (js can create a new window and open it or in tabgroup)
2. Window can't include alloy in
   .xml file( require .xml file ,you should delete alloy tag)